# html + css formatting font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have been using `<font>` tags to style my fonts but after running page through html validator I have found out these are now not used.

so my question is what would be the best way to achieve the following without the use of the font tags.

```
echo  "<b><font size ='2'> ".$horse."</b></font> <font size ='2'>".horselastrace($horse, $db)."</font><b><font color='red'>".horsebeatenfav($horse, $db)."</font></b>"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<span style='font-size:12px;'>insert code</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing in php, try:

```
echo '<span class="small">'.$horse.horselastrace($horse, $db).'</span><span class="red">'.horsebeatenfav($horse, $db).'</span>';
```

with a style sheet (css file):

```
span.small {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: bold;
}
span.red {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

Also, `<b>` tags are deprecated, and your HTML tags should not be ordered like this:

```
<div><p>code</div></p>
```

but enclosed like this:

```
<div><p>code</p></div>
```

Comment: Alternatively `<b>` can now be replaced with `<strong>`  :)